# Can't pickup sphere with Vive controller. Collision not detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, virtual-reality

I am doing a tutorial from VR Dev School. The lesson is Picking Up an Object and Parent the Transform. This is the code I copied exactly from the lesson. I have the script and a sphere collider attached to controlller(left). I've tried toggling 'is trigger' on/off. The collision is not being detected in the console. I am not receiving any errors or warnings.

Any assistance is appreciated and I will answer any questions

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SteamVR_TrackedObject))]

public class PickupParent : MonoBehaviour {

    SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;
    SteamVR_Controller.Device device;


    void Awake () {
        trackedObj = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>();

    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);
        if(device.GetTouch(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("You are holding 'Touch' on the trigger");
        }
        if (device.GetTouchDown(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("You activated touchdown on the trigger");
        }
        if (device.GetTouchUp(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("You activated TouchUp on the trigger");
        }
        if (device.GetPress(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("You are holding 'Press' on the trigger");
        }
        if (device.GetPressDown(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("You activated press down on the trigger");
        }
        if (device.GetPressUp(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("You activated press Up on the trigger");
        }
    }
    void onTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        Debug.Log("You have collided with " + col.name + " and activated onTriggerStay");
        if (device.GetTouch(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("You have collided with " + col.name + " while holding down Touch");
            col.attachedRigidbody.isKinematic = true;
            col.gameObject.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `Debug.Log("You have collided with " + col.name + " and activated onTriggerStay");` is showing.....Is `Debug.Log("You have collided with " + col.name + " while holding down Touch");` showing the Console log too?

Comment: No, so it is detecting touches and presses on the Vive controller in the console. No detection of collision.

Comment: You should update this code with a complete code

Comment: Sorry. Thought it might be redundant. It's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple mistake. It should be `OnTriggerStay` not `onTriggerStay`. Please capitalize the `O` and trigger/collision should be detected.

Comment: Nice. Had to test that to figure it out. You can accept as answer if your problem is solved.